# Python can't send data to axios request

Tags: javascript, python, flask, post, axios

I have a dilemma. When I send a request from Postman, I get the server status 200 and the required data. When with Axios, the server status is 500 internal server error and errors in logs:

```
2020-08-17T09:25:28.361222+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-17 09:25:28,359] ERROR in app: Exception on / [POST]
2020-08-17T09:25:28.361223+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-08-17T09:25:28.361224+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
2020-08-17T09:25:28.361224+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2020-08-17T09:25:28.361224+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
2020-08-17T09:25:28.361225+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2020-08-17T09:25:28.361225+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
2020-08-17T09:25:28.361226+00:00 app[web.1]:     return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
2020-08-17T09:25:28.361226+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
2020-08-17T09:25:28.361226+00:00 app[web.1]:     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2020-08-17T09:25:28.361227+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
2020-08-17T09:25:28.361228+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise value
2020-08-17T09:25:28.361228+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
2020-08-17T09:25:28.361229+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2020-08-17T09:25:28.361229+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
2020-08-17T09:25:28.361230+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2020-08-17T09:25:28.361230+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app.py", line 14, in index
2020-08-17T09:25:28.361230+00:00 app[web.1]:     result = scrapper_amaz.main_scrapper(amazon_url)
2020-08-17T09:25:28.361231+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/scrapper_amaz.py", line 460, in main_scrapper
2020-08-17T09:25:28.361231+00:00 app[web.1]:     flagged_data = save_to_mongo(data)
2020-08-17T09:25:28.361232+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/scrapper_amaz.py", line 440, in save_to_mongo
2020-08-17T09:25:28.361232+00:00 app[web.1]:     data = collection.find_one({'url':document.get('url')})
2020-08-17T09:25:28.361304+00:00 app[web.1]: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

This is my axios request:

```
const form = new FormData()
form.append('url', `https://amazon.com/dp/${asin}`)
axios({
  "method": "POST",
  "url": url,
  "data": form,
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
  }
}).then((response) => {
  console.log(response)
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error)
})
```

This is my python app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, json         # import flask
from flask_cors import CORS
import scrapper_amaz

app = Flask(__name__)             # create an app instance
CORS(app)

@app.route("/", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])                   # at the end point /
def index():                      # call method hello
  if request.method == 'POST':
    amazon_url = request.form['url']
    result = scrapper_amaz.main_scrapper(amazon_url)
    if '_id' in result:
      del result['_id']
    
    result = json.dumps(result)
    result = result.replace('"[','[').replace(']"',']')
    return json.dumps(json.loads(result), indent=2)

  if request.method == 'GET':
    return render_template('index.html')         # which returns "hello world"

if __name__ == "__main__":        # on running python app.py
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)                     # run the flask app
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you post the code in `/app/scrapper_amaz.py`? That's where the problem is happening. `document` is undefined. You might need to set `User-Agent` headers in your requests when scraping.

Comment: @PeacefulJames I can't post full, because there is a lot of code. I have this User-Agent headers: `headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}`
`ua=UserAgent()`

Comment: OK well the problem is that `document` is `None` so how is `document` being declared/set?